# Baixar arquivo setando o header

Tags: python, python-3.x

boa tarde. Como eu consigo baixar um arquivo de um site na URL setando o cabeçalho? Por exemplo, tenho um arquivo em um site e quero baixar em python, simplesmente me retorna um erro 403, então, como eu consigo setar o cabeçalho que irei usar? Acredito que assim não irá dar o erro 403.

```
import requests

url = "http://example.com/uploads/archive.ts"

headerr = {'Host': 'example.com',
           'User-agent': 'Windows 10',
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
           'Accept-language': 'en-US,en; q=0.5',
           'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
           'Connection': 'close'}
           #tenho que fazer o download do arquivo usando o cabeçalho acima. Como faço?

try:
    requisicao = requests.get(url, headers=headerr)
    print("Feito.")
except Exception as e:
    print("Erro", e)
```

Answer (score 1):

A forma de passar os cabeçalhos está correta. Porém, você não está passando nenhum cabeçalho de autenticação, como `Authorization`.

Você precisa entender como o serviço espera essa autenticação e então aplicá-la.

Comment: Então... Na verdade é assim, ao abrir o site com o arquivo no meu navegador, por ser um arquivo .ts, ele faz o download na hora. Mas na hora de mandar a requisição setando o header, em vez de baixar o arquivo, ele apenas mostra o conteúdo dele. Se eu não setar nada no header, ele me retorna um 403. O plano era eu fazer uma requisição setando o header e conseguir fazer o download, saca? Valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Talvez a autenticação seja via cookie e seu Browser já esteja autenticado, por isso consegue realizar a requisição sem problemas.